# paint $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two colors

Tags: set-theory

Can we paint $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two colors (say, black and white) so that any horizontal line pass through *countable* black points and any vertical line pass through *countable* white points?

---

**Update.** I was amazed that this is a classical problem! Actually what I wanted to do is using set theory to prove that there exist incomparable Turing degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the continuum hypothesis holds, the answer is yes by a nice straightforward transfinite recursion:

By CH, let $\{l_\eta:\eta<\omega_1\}$ be a list of all the vertical and horizontal lines in the plane. We build a coloring of the plane by recursion, as follows: at step $\alpha$, we take the points on line $l_\alpha$ that haven't been colored yet and color them

- White, if $l_\alpha$ is a horizontal line
- Black, if $l_\alpha$ is a vertical line.

For each line $l$ (horizontal or vertical), only countably many other lines "came before" it in our construction. The lines of the same type as $l$ don't intersect $l$, so how we colored them won't affect what the points on $l$ will be colored; and each of the lines of the opposite type intersect $l$ exactly once. So only countably many points on $l$ will be colored "wrong" (that is: black if $l$ is horizontal, white if $l$ is vertical).

---

I suspect that this is not doable in ZFC alone.

Comment: Or, just identify $\mathbb{R}$ with $\omega_1$ and color $(x,y)$ black iff $x\leq y$ in the order of $\omega_1$.  I have a vague memory that it is a theorem of Sierpinski that this statement is equivalent to CH but don't remember how to prove the converse at the moment.

Comment: @EricWofsey That's not only much slicker than what I did, it's also an instance of a generally really useful trick.

Comment: Though mine is slicker, I actually like your argument better in a lot of ways.  It's a much more general technique that beginners in set theory often fail to appreciate the power of.